# Error while running report in report studio cognos 7.2

Tags: report, cognos

I have created the report in report studio 7.2.
The report is working fine when I am using the date filter(Date between '6/27/2018' and '6/28/2018') inside the sql query.
However when I created the detail filter so that it allows you to select the date, its giving me the error

> "An error occurred while performing operation 'sqlScrollBulkFetch' status='-232', UDA-SQL-0107 A general exception has occurred during the operation
>
> "fetch".RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSLayoutAssembly.cpp(79): QFException: CCL_RETHROW ".

Any help will be appreciated.
I am creating this report for other users so it must have the date filter to select any date.

Thank you

Comment: You provided a working SQL filter. However, you didn't provide the syntax of the Cognos filter. Seeing the actual Cognos filter with the parameter reference will help diagnose the problem.

Comment: [Date] between ?BeginDate? and ?EndDate? This is the filter, I am using in detail filter expression.

Comment: Have you tried casting the result of the parameter, e.g. cast(?BeginDate?,date). What kind of prompt is being generated? Is it a date prompt or a text prompt?

Comment: I tried casting the result but its still giving me same error.

Comment: Its a date prompt, it was working before but all of a sudden start giving error.:(

Comment: Please show the SQL.  In the report, go to the query, from properties, select Generated SQL. You may be prompted for the dates. This will show the SQL that would be used.  Sharing this information will help us so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Change the Fact column to an Identifier.

Steps:

Open Framework Manager with the model used with the problem report.
Expand the correct Namespace and Model Query Subject that contains the problem column.
Click on the Query Item that causes the error.
In the Properties pane, change the Usage property from "Fact" to "Identifier"
Save and publish the package.
Run the report.